FFmpeg fails to draw text
I've rarely used ffmpeg before, so, sorry If the question is too dumb.
I have a problem adding a text layer to a video frame using ffmpeg.
This is my current code:
import subprocess
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QImage
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLabel

class VideoThumbnailLabel(QLabel):
    def __init__(self, file_path, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.video = video
        video_duration = self.get_video_duration(file_path)
        thumbnail_path = self.get_thumbnail(file_path, video_duration)
        if thumbnail_path:
            self.setPixmap(QPixmap(thumbnail_path).scaled(160, 90, Qt.KeepAspectRatio))
        self.setToolTip(f"{video.title}\n{video.description}")

    def get_video_duration(self, video_path):
        """Returns the duration of the video in seconds."""
        command = [
            'ffprobe', '-v', 'error', '-show_entries',
            'format=duration', '-of',
            'default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1', video_path
        ]
        try:
            result = subprocess.run(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)
            if result.returncode != 0:
                print(f"ffprobe error: {result.stderr}")
                return 0
            duration = float(result.stdout)
            return int(duration)  # Returning duration as an integer for simplicity
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error getting video duration: {e}")
            return 0

    def get_thumbnail(self, video_path, duration):
        """Generates a thumbnail with the video duration overlaid."""
        output_path = "thumbnail.jpg"  # Temporary thumbnail file
        duration_str = f"{duration // 3600:02d}:{(duration % 3600) // 60:02d}:{duration % 60:02d}"
        command = [
            'ffmpeg', '-i', video_path,
            '-ss', '00:00:01',  # Time to take the screenshot
            '-frames:v', '1',  # Number of frames to capture
            '-vf', f"drawtext=text='Duration: {duration_str}':x=10:y=10:fontsize=24:fontcolor=white",
            '-q:v', '2',  # Output quality
            '-y',  # Overwrite output files without asking
            output_path
        ]
        try:
            result = subprocess.run(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
            if result.returncode != 0:
                print(f"ffmpeg error: {result.stderr}")
                return None
            return output_path
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error generating thumbnail with duration: {e}")
            return None

and it is used like this:
for i, video in enumerate(self.videos):
    video_widget = VideoThumbnailLabel(video.file)
    video_widget.mousePressEvent = lambda event, v=video: self.onThumbnailClick(
        v
    )
    self.layout.addWidget(video_widget, i // 3, i % 3)

I'm facing a problem where I am not able to get the thumbnail if I try to add the duration (I've tested it without the draw filter and worked fine)
I get this error (from the result.returncode) that I'm not able to comprehend:
ffmpeg error: b"ffmpeg version 6.1.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2023 the FFmpeg developers\n  built with Apple clang version 15.0.0 (clang-1500.1.0.2.5)\n  configuration: --prefix=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ffmpeg/6.1.1_4 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags='-Wl,-ld_classic' --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libaribb24 --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libharfbuzz --enable-libjxl --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librist --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenvino --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-libzmq --enable-libzimg --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-videotoolbox --enable-audiotoolbox --enable-neon\n  libavutil      58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100\n  libavcodec     60. 31.102 / 60. 31.102\n  libavformat    60. 16.100 / 60. 16.100\n  libavdevice    60.  3.100 / 60.  3.100\n  libavfilter     9. 12.100 /  9. 12.100\n  libswscale      7.  5.100 /  7.  5.100\n  libswresample   4. 12.100 /  4. 12.100\n  libpostproc    57.  3.100 / 57.  3.100\nInput #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/Users/edoardo/Projects/work/test/BigBuckBunny.mp4':\n  Metadata:\n    major_brand     : mp42\n    minor_version   : 0\n    compatible_brands: isomavc1mp42\n    creation_time   : 2010-01-10T08:29:06.000000Z\n  Duration: 00:09:56.47, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2119 kb/s\n  Stream #0:0[0x1](und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 125 kb/s (default)\n    Metadata:\n      creation_time   : 2010-01-10T08:29:06.000000Z\n      handler_name    : (C) 2007 Google Inc. v08.13.2007.\n      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]\n  Stream #0:1[0x2](und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(progressive), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 1991 kb/s, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 24k tbn (default)\n    Metadata:\n      creation_time   : 2010-01-10T08:29:06.000000Z\n      handler_name    : (C) 2007 Google Inc. v08.13.2007.\n      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]\n[Parsed_drawtext_0 @ 0x60000331cd10] Both text and text file provided. Please provide only one\n[AVFilterGraph @ 0x600002018000] Error initializing filters\n[vost#0:0/mjpeg @ 0x13ce0c7e0] Error initializing a simple filtergraph\nError opening output file thumbnail.jpg.\nError opening output files: Invalid argument\n"

I've installed both ffmpeg and ffmprobe in my machine:
┌(edoardomacbook-air)-[~/Projects/work/tests-scripts]                                                                                                                                   
└─ $ ffmpeg -version && ffprobe -version                                                                                                                                                              2 ⚙ 
ffmpeg version 6.1.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2023 the FFmpeg developers
built with Apple clang version 15.0.0 (clang-1500.1.0.2.5)
configuration: --prefix=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ffmpeg/6.1.1_4 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags='-Wl,-ld_classic' --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libaribb24 --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libharfbuzz --enable-libjxl --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librist --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenvino --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-libzmq --enable-libzimg --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-videotoolbox --enable-audiotoolbox --enable-neon
libavutil      58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
libavcodec     60. 31.102 / 60. 31.102
libavformat    60. 16.100 / 60. 16.100
libavdevice    60.  3.100 / 60.  3.100
libavfilter     9. 12.100 /  9. 12.100
libswscale      7.  5.100 /  7.  5.100
libswresample   4. 12.100 /  4. 12.100
libpostproc    57.  3.100 / 57.  3.100
ffprobe version 6.1.1 Copyright (c) 2007-2023 the FFmpeg developers
built with Apple clang version 15.0.0 (clang-1500.1.0.2.5)
configuration: --prefix=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ffmpeg/6.1.1_4 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags='-Wl,-ld_classic' --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libaribb24 --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libharfbuzz --enable-libjxl --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librist --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenvino --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-libzmq --enable-libzimg --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-videotoolbox --enable-audiotoolbox --enable-neon
libavutil      58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
libavcodec     60. 31.102 / 60. 31.102
libavformat    60. 16.100 / 60. 16.100
libavdevice    60.  3.100 / 60.  3.100
libavfilter     9. 12.100 /  9. 12.100
libswscale      7.  5.100 /  7.  5.100
libswresample   4. 12.100 /  4. 12.100
libpostproc    57.  3.100 / 57.  3.100

Does anyone see the problem?

P.S.: I know that I havent provided a minimal reproducible example, but since I don't know where the problem lies I didn't want to exclude anything

Copying/pasting the quoted part of the ffmpeg error and printing it results in this key line: [Parsed_drawtext_0 @ 0x60000331cd10] Both text and text file provided. Please provide only one.  The error may be solved via this thread (specifically you may need to tinker with the string quoting). There are further errors that follow but you should correct the first one and see if the rest get resolved.
